# Unable to load Vector Layer in standalone application developed using QGIS libraries?

Tags: pyqgis

I suspect that the problem is due to the Prefix path. My ubuntu system does not have it set. What to do?

```
>>> print(QgsApplication.showSettings())
Application state:
QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var:       
Prefix:     
Plugin Path:        
Package Data Path:  
Active Theme Name:  
Active Theme Path:  /themes//icons/
Default Theme Path: :/images/themes/default/
SVG Search Paths:   
User DB Path:   /resources/qgis.db
Auth DB Path:   qgis-auth.db
```